# How to find out how many trading days in each month in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this. The time span is 10 years. Because it's Chinese market data, and China has Lunar Holidays. So each year have different holiday times in terms of the western calendar.

When it is a holiday, the stock market does not open, so it is a non-trading day. Weekends are non-trading days too.

I want to find out which month of which year has the least number of trading days, and most importantly, what number is that.

There are not repeated days.

```
        date change   open   high    low  close volume
1 1995-01-03 -1.233 637.72 647.71 630.53 639.88 234518
2 1995-01-04  2.177 641.90 655.51 638.86 653.81 422220
3 1995-01-05 -1.058 656.20 657.45 645.81 646.89 430123
4 1995-01-06 -0.948 642.75 643.89 636.33 640.76 487482
5 1995-01-09 -2.308 637.52 637.55 625.04 625.97 509851
6 1995-01-10 -2.503 616.16 617.60 607.06 610.30 606925
```

Comment: You can check with `bizdays` package

Answer (score 2):

If there are not repeated days, you can count days per month and year by:

```
   library(data.table)                                                                                                                                                                                                                "maxx"))), .Names = c("X2005", "X2006", "X2007", "X2008"))
    library(lubridate)
    dt <- as.data.table(dt)
    dt_days <- dt[, .(count_day=.N), by=.(year(date), month(date))]
```

Then you only need to do this to get the min:

```
dt_days[count_day==min(count_day)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The chron and bizdays packages deal with business days but neither actually contains a usable calendar of holidays limiting their usefulness.
We will use chron below assuming you have defined the `.Holidays` vector of dates that are holidays.  (If you run the code below without doing that only weekdays will be regarded as business days as the default `.Holidays` vector supplied by chron has very few dates in it.)  `DF` has 120 rows (one row for each year/month) and the last line subsets that to just the month in each year having least business days.

```
library(chron)
library(zoo)

st <- as.yearmon("2001-01")
en <- as.yearmon("2010-12")
ym <- seq(st, en, 1/12)  # sequence of year/months of interest

# no of business days in each yearmonth
busdays <- sapply(ym, function(x) {
  s <- seq(as.Date(x), as.Date(x, frac = 1), "day")
  sum(!is.weekend(s) & !is.holiday(s))
})

# data frame with one row per year/month
yr <- as.integer(ym)
DF <- data.frame(year = yr, month = cycle(ym), yearmon = ym, busdays)

# data frame with one row per year
wx.min <- ave(busdays, yr, FUN = function(x) which.min(x) == seq_along(x))
DF[wx.min == 1, ]
```

giving:

```
    year month  yearmon busdays
2   2001     2 Feb 2001      20
14  2002     2 Feb 2002      20
26  2003     2 Feb 2003      20
38  2004     2 Feb 2004      20
50  2005     2 Feb 2005      20
62  2006     2 Feb 2006      20
74  2007     2 Feb 2007      20
95  2008    11 Nov 2008      20
98  2009     2 Feb 2009      20
110 2010     2 Feb 2010      20
```